# Why Typescript allow me to do this? No length check for Array

Tags: typescript, typechecking

Why Typescript allow me to use any array element without forcing me to check if the index is valid?

Here is what I mean

```typescript
function return_array(p:boolean):string[]{
    return (p) ? ['s'] : [];
}

const arr = return_array(false);
arr[30].toUpperCase();
```

This will obviously lead me to an error

```
Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
```

Is this by design or am I missing something?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgE4FMZlRA+gQ1VXwE8AKABwC4AjBBAG3XwgEoqBnGVOCAcwDaAXQDewAJAYsOZJVbIA-MgEByDiqHIqyoQG5gAX2DAoSLskKpkAXjSZseS6TIh8DDulb7LAgMwAGIQA6GAQAVQoKdFQAYXwPMi9gIA)

#### Edit

The real function is something like:

```typescript
function return_array(p:boolean):string[]{
    // querying the db, it can return an empty array. 
    return db_response;
}
```

Comment: The length of the array varies at runtime and it's not something TypeScript should be checking against. You should probably perform a sanity check on `arr[30]` first before attempting to chain anything to it. [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and/or [null coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) are your best friends, e.g. `a[30]?.toUpperCase();`

Comment: You can return a tuple `[string]`

Answer (score 3):

By default, TS doesn't check if the value exists under a particular index in dynamic arrays (`string[]`). To ensure the type safety, you can do one of (or both):

1. Narrow the return type to `[string] | []` (since this is what your function is actually returning).
2. Set [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) in your TS config (this will force you to checks for `undefined` elements anytime you're accessing an index).

Comment: As far as I know, arrays in JavaScript are always dynamic (as with almost everything in JavaScript). I fail to see how your first point could solve the issue at hand. But I find your second point interesting; I didn't know about that compiler option, so I will certainly look into it. :)

Comment: @BartHofland “I fail to see how your first point could solve the issue at hand” Did you try the code? It will give you the error that you want.  It uses a union of two tuple types to say that the returned array will have either 0 or 1 elements.  So setting or accessing anything outside of those bounds is not allowed by TS.

Comment: @LindaPaiste . . . I must admit that I haven't tried the code. But after reading your explanation, it makes perfect sense to me now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your function is explicitly returning `string[]` and typescript believes it. here's what you could do: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgE4FMZlRA%20gQ1VXwE8AKABwC5kAjBBAG3XwgEoaYSL0ERkKydAA8Y6CABMAzshiow6ZAH5kUuXAgBzANoBdZDT3IA3sACQGLDmSVlybQHIpD-Yd1tk%20GVx58BQ0XFpWXlFFTVUDR1Xe10AbmAAX2BgKCQ1TyJkAF40TGw8QmJyEHxGKXQ2BKLtAGYABl0AOhgEAFUKHlQAYS90MirgIA)

Comment: My real function doesn't really use a boolean to know if the array it is empty or not. It was just a way. In general I am querying the DB and the array can be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the value of parameter `p`, your function `return_array` returns either an array containing a single element `'s'` (when `p == true`) or an empty array (when `p == false`).

You call `return_array(false)` and store the result in a variable called `arr`. That means, that `arr` will be an empty array.

Then you want to access the 31st element of that empty array (note that array indexes start at 0). That element is `undefined`, since the array has no elements at all.

You cannot call `toUpperCase` on `undefined`, since `undefined` and `null` have no members.

Note that TypeScript just compiles to JavaScript. And the above code is valid JavaScript. The following code would work fine as well:

```
const arr: string[] = [];
arr[30] = 's';
```

This will result in an array where `arr[0]` to `arr[29]` are `undefined` and `arr[30]` will be `'s'`.

TypeScript's behavior is correct. It should not override any behavior from JavaScript. It's simply valid to access an out-of-bounds element in a JavaScript array.